# Using OpenCV3.0 with Qt5 on Win10, Debug Assertion Failed

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, qt5, assert

I am writing a code to recognize cars in a video. Here is the code:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#define SHOW_FLAG false
#define DEBUG_BY_STEP false

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
 QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

QImage MainWindow::Mat2QImage(Mat cvImg)
{
    QImage qImg;
    if(cvImg.channels()==3)                         //3 channels color image
    {
        cv::cvtColor(cvImg,cvImg,CV_BGR2RGB);
        qImg =QImage((const unsigned char*)(cvImg.data),
                    cvImg.cols, cvImg.rows,
                    cvImg.cols*cvImg.channels(),
                    QImage::Format_RGB888);
    }
    else if(cvImg.channels()==1)                    //grayscale image
    {
        qImg =QImage((const unsigned char*)(cvImg.data),
                    cvImg.cols,cvImg.rows,
                    cvImg.cols*cvImg.channels(),
                    QImage::Format_Indexed8);
    }
    else
    {
        qImg =QImage((const unsigned char*)(cvImg.data),
                    cvImg.cols,cvImg.rows,
                    cvImg.cols*cvImg.channels(),
                    QImage::Format_RGB888);
    }
    return qImg;
}

void MainWindow::updateFrame()
{
    frame1 = frame2.clone();
    capture.read(frame2);
    if(!frame2.empty())
    {
        proc();
    }
    frameCnt++;
}

void MainWindow::proc()
{
    /*== == == == == == == == == == = step2.1 Variable definition and Initialization == == == == == == == == == == == == == == =*/
    vector<Blob> currentBlobs;             //blob in current frame
    vector<Blob> tempBlobs;                //temp blob
    Mat frame1Copy, frame2Copy;            //copy completely
    Mat imgDifference;                     //frame difference
    Mat imgThresh;                         //binarization

    /*== == == == == == == == == == = step2.2 denoise and find contours == == == == == == == == == == == == == == =*/
    cv::resize(frame1, frame1Copy, Size((int)(frame1.cols / resizeWidthCoefficient), (int)(frame1.rows / resizeHeightCoefficient))); //resize
    cv::resize(frame2, frame2Copy, Size((int)(frame2.cols / resizeWidthCoefficient), (int)(frame2.rows / resizeHeightCoefficient)));
    cvtColor(frame1Copy, frame1Copy, CV_BGR2GRAY);                    //to gray
    cvtColor(frame2Copy, frame2Copy, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    GaussianBlur(frame1Copy, frame1Copy, Size(5, 5), 0);              //GaussianBlur for smoothing
    GaussianBlur(frame2Copy, frame2Copy, Size(5, 5), 0);
    absdiff(frame1Copy, frame2Copy, imgDifference);                   //frame difference
    //GaussianBlur(imgDifference, imgDifference, Size(5, 5), 0);
    //threshold(imgDifference, imgThresh, 30, 255.0, CV_THRESH_BINARY); //binarization
    adaptiveThreshold(imgDifference, imgThresh, 255,              CV_ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, CV_THRESH_BINARY_INV, 25, 10);
    if (SHOW_FLAG) imshow("imgThresh", imgThresh);

    Mat structuringElement3x3   = getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size(3, 3)); //definition of different kernels, big kernel for noisy image
    Mat structuringElement5x5   = getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size(5, 5));
    //Mat structuringElement7x7   = getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size(7, 7));
    //Mat structuringElement15x15 = getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size(15, 15));

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        dilate(imgThresh, imgThresh, structuringElement3x3, Point(-1, -1), 2);
        erode(imgThresh, imgThresh, structuringElement5x5);
    }

    Mat imgThreshCopy = imgThresh.clone();
    vector<vector<Point> > contours; //contours
    findContours(imgThreshCopy, contours, RETR_EXTERNAL, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
    if (SHOW_FLAG) showContours(imgThresh.size(), contours, "imgContours");

    vector<vector<Point> > convexHulls(contours.size());

    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) convexHull(contours[i], convexHulls[i]);

    if (SHOW_FLAG) showContours(imgThresh.size(), convexHulls, "imgConvexHulls");
    for (auto &convexHull : convexHulls) //filter with heuristic knowledge
    {
        Blob possibleBlob(convexHull, (int)lineStart.size());
        Rect possibleBoundingBox = possibleBlob.getBoundingBox();
        if (
            possibleBoundingBox.area() > minBlobArea &&
            possibleBoundingBox.area() < maxBlobArea &&
            possibleBlob.getRatio() > minBlobRatio &&
            possibleBlob.getRatio() < maxBlobRatio &&
            possibleBoundingBox.width > minBlobWidth &&
            possibleBoundingBox.width < maxBlobWidth &&
            possibleBoundingBox.height > minBlobheight &&
            possibleBoundingBox.height < maxBlobheight &&
            possibleBlob.getDiagonalLength() > minBlobDiagonal &&
            possibleBlob.getDiagonalLength() < maxBlobDiagonal &&
            (contourArea(possibleBlob.getContour()) / (double)possibleBoundingBox.area()) > 0.50        //contour area / rect area
            )
            tempBlobs.push_back(possibleBlob);
    }
    for (int i = 0, j ; i < tempBlobs.size(); i++) //filter with inclusion
    {
        for (j = 0; j < tempBlobs.size(); j++)
        if (j != i && isOverlapped(tempBlobs[i].getBoundingBox(), tempBlobs[j].getBoundingBox())) break; //is covered
        if (j == tempBlobs.size())
            currentBlobs.push_back(tempBlobs[i]);
    }
    if (SHOW_FLAG) showContours(imgThresh.size(), currentBlobs, "imgcurrentBlobs");

    matchBlobs(blobs, currentBlobs, frame2Copy);
    if (SHOW_FLAG) showContours(imgThresh.size(), blobs, "imgBlobs");

    /*== == == == == == == == == == = step2.3 counting and draw blobs == == == == == == == == == == == == == == =*/
    frame2Copy = frame2.clone();
    drawBlob(blobs, frame2Copy);
    for (int i = 0; i < lineStart.size(); i++)
    {
        if (isCrossLine(blobs, lineStart[i], lineEnd[i], cnt[i], i)) //some blob has crossed the line
            line(frame2Copy, lineStart[i], lineEnd[i], GREEN, lineThickness);
        else
            line(frame2Copy, lineStart[i], lineEnd[i], RED, lineThickness);
    }
    drawCnt(cnt, frame2Copy);

    Mat temp = frame2Copy.clone();
    //QImage image2 = Mat2QImage(temp);
    //ui->label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image2).scaled(ui->label->width(),ui->label->height(),Qt::KeepAspectRatio));
    imshow("frame2Copy", frame2Copy);
}

void MainWindow::on_proc_clicked()
{
    crossingLineEnd.clear();
    crossingLineStart.clear();
    blobs.clear();
    lineStart.clear();
    lineEnd.clear();
    cnt.clear();

    /*****************************************************/

    pair<double, double> straightStart(0.1, 0.8);
    pair<double, double> straightEnd(0.9, 0.8);
   // pair<double, double> leftStart(0.1, 0);
   // pair<double, double> leftEnd(0.1, 0.8);
   // pair<double, double> rightStart(0.9, 0);
   // pair<double, double> rightEnd(0.9, 0.8);

    crossingLineStart.push_back(straightStart);
  //  crossingLineStart.push_back(leftStart);
  //  crossingLineStart.push_back(rightStart);
    crossingLineEnd.push_back(straightEnd);
  //  crossingLineEnd.push_back(leftEnd);
  //  crossingLineEnd.push_back(rightEnd);

    for(int i=0;i<crossingLineStart.size();i++)
        cnt.push_back(0);
    frameCnt = 2;

    if(capture.isOpened())
        capture.release();

    QString filename =QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,tr("Open Video File"),".",tr("Video Files(*.avi *.mp4 *.flv *.mkv)"));
    capture.open(filename.toLocal8Bit().data());


    if (!capture.isOpened()) //cannot open the video
    {
        cout << "can't open the video!" << endl;
        system("pause");
        return;
    }

    capture.read(frame1);
    capture.read(frame2);

    for (int i = 0; i < crossingLineStart.size(); i++)       //scale to coordinate
    {
        int x = (int)((frame1.cols - 1) * crossingLineStart[i].first);
        int y = (int)((frame1.rows - 1) * crossingLineStart[i].second);
        Point start(x, y);
        lineStart.push_back(start);

        x = (int)((frame1.cols - 1) * crossingLineEnd[i].first);
        y = (int)((frame1.rows - 1) * crossingLineEnd[i].second);
        Point end(x, y);

        lineEnd.push_back(end);
    }

    if(capture.isOpened())
    {
        double rate = capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);
        proc();

        timer = new QTimer(this);
        timer->setInterval(1000/rate);
        connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(updateFrame()));
        timer->start();
    }
}
```

The code is used to recognize the moving cars in a video and mark the car with a rectangle blob. I tried two videos. The problem is, for one video, nothing happened and every thing is OK. But for another video, at first, it's OK. Then, after a few frames have been processed, I occurred this problem:

Debug Assertion Failed!
Program:
...CV-Desktop_Qt_5_8_0MSVC2015_64bit-Debug\debug\WIC_OpenCV.exe
File:E:\VisualStudio\VC\INCLUDE\xmemory0
Line: 106
Expression:"(_Ptr_user & (_BIG_ALLOCATION_ALIGNMENT - 1))==0" && 0

I do not understand why. I tried to debug it, and it seems the error occurs at sometime the last codes in function proc() was executed:

```
Mat temp = frame2Copy.clone();
//QImage image2 = Mat2QImage(temp);
//ui->label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image2).scaled(ui->label->width(),ui->label->height(),Qt::KeepAspectRatio));
imshow("frame2Copy", frame2Copy);
```

I am frustrated. Can someone help me? Thanks very much.

Comment: Well, I found that the problem is caused by the opencv lib function:findContours(). My situation is very like this:http://techqa.info/programming/question/42315868/Why-does-findcontours-crushes-the-program-in-Qt-, except I am using opencv3.0

Answer (score 0):

After a long time searching, I found that it was the fault of the opencv lib. I was using OpenCV3.0, after I changed to OpenCV3.2, the problem is solved. I do not understand why.